# Bug-hunter finds error but it shouldn't (false positive)

Tags: init-file, package, require, debug, session

I suspect I'm doing something very stupid but I can't figure out what. I have some problems with Eshell, and I was advised to use Bug-hunter. I installed it through Elpa. When I launch it (`M-x bug-hunter-init-file`), I am asked which type of debug I want, and I choose interactive (`i`), then I am presented with the initial menu. Upon pressing `6` to start, A new Emacs frame opens up, but here's the catch! It gives an error in the echo area (`let: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, windsize`). The Emacs session is basic (as if I launched it with `-q`). When I close it, I answer `n` (since the error is not present), and I got this:

```
Test failed.
The assertion returned nil after loading the entire file.
Remember, the assertion must be an expression that returns
non-nil in your current (problematic) Emacs state, AND that
returns nil on a clean Emacs instance.
If you're unsure how to write an assertion, you can try the interactive
hunt instead, or see some examples in the Readme:
    https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter
interactive
^L
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Note that, if I try to automatically debug my init-file, I got an error on

```
  The following error was signaled here:
    (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "windsize")
  Caused by the following expression:
    (require 'windsize)
```

like if windsize causes an error. However, in my init file all works good (checking with `--debug-init`), and btw if I try to remove that line it seems all require` are errors.
**Is this normal?**

Comment: have you tried installing `windsize`?

Comment: It is already installed, that's why I put its `require` :-)   Moreover, it seems that even subsequent `require` cause error

Comment: _worksforme_. make sure it's in your `load-path`.

Comment: I don't know, it actually is in my `load-path` :-/  Apparently, I'll have to debug the bug-hunter :-)  I'll try bisecting with git

Comment: Consider reporting the problem to the maintainer of `bug-hunter`.